# Trying to make a variable that is being changed dynamically in a private scope global

Tags: javascript, function, object, dynamic, checkbox

I think I got the Title right but here is what I want to do

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var oVars = {};
        var withones;
         etc //didnt work in what of my attempts to declare variables here so didnt cont.
        $('.checkboxes :checkbox').click(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if($(this).is(':checked')){


                    oVars[this.id] = true;
                    console.log( oVars)
                }
                if(!$this.is(':checked')){
                    oVars[this.id] = false;
                    console.log( oVars)
                }
```

at this point it is to my understanding that the oVars is  like

```
               oVars{
                    withones : true,
                    withoutOnes : false, //if unchecked
                    dispReg :true //if checked
                }
```

I see the values of the properties change when I check the boxes

I want to be able to do something like this (globally):

```
               var withOnes = oVars['withones'];
                var withoutOnes = oVars['withoutOnes'];
                etc;
```

I want to declare these variables globally and I want their values to change according to true or false because that is what is being assigned in the if $(this).is(':checked') to demonstrate which one is checked. The reason why I want to do this is that i want to make a function where the argument is the updated value.

```
});
```

I would make a code like below somewhere else in the code

```
if(withOnes){ // I want withOnes to be true if checked false if unchecked
            process code if true
        }
```

I tried to do something like below. please help me figure out how to change these variables value so I could use the variable other places in the code

```
       if(withones = true){
            console.log("withones checked")
        }
        if(withones = false){
            console.log("withones unchecked")
        }
```

but only "withones checked" was displayed every time the checkbox was changes.

`});`

HTML:

```
        <div>
        <div class="checkboxes">
            <div class="dificulty">
                <label for="withones" class="labelOuter" > 
                    <input type="checkbox" id= "withones" class = "regular-checkbox big-checkbox"><label for="withones"></label> <span class="label">With ones</span>
                </label>
                <label for="withoutOnes" class="labelOuter" > 
                    <input type="checkbox" id = "withoutOnes" class= "regular-checkbox big-checkbox"><label for="withoutOnes"></label><span class="label">Without ones</span>
                </label>
            </div> <!-- dificulty -->

            <div class="view">
                <label for="dispReg" class="labelOuter" > 
                    <input type="checkbox" id = "dispReg" class= "regular-checkbox big-checkbox"><label for="dispReg"></label><span class="label">Display cash register</span>
                </label>
                <label for="hideReg" class="labelOuter" > 
                    <input type="checkbox" id = "hideReg" class= "regular-checkbox big-checkbox"><label for="hideReg"></label><span class="label" title ="gets rid of image">hide cash register</span>
                </label>
                <label for="hideItems" class="labelOuter" > 
                    <input type="checkbox" id = "hideItems" class= "regular-checkbox big-checkbox"><label for="hideItems"></label><span class="label">hide items</span>
                </label>
                <label for="showItems" class="labelOuter" > 
                    <input type="checkbox" id = "showItems" class= "regular-checkbox big-checkbox"><label for="showItems"></label><span class="label">show items</span>
                </label>

              </div> <!-- view -->

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[an updated jsfiddle after reviewing an answer](http://jsfiddle.net/ot38Lz70/1/)

Comment: Your jsfiddle-link seems to be empty or is it just me?

Comment: my bad http://jsfiddle.net/ot38Lz70/1/

Comment: //if i take this code out of the click event it wont work

     `if(withones){
      alert("checked");
     }
     if(!withones){
      alert("unchecked");
     }`
so i guess I have to work in the click event unless there is another way?  with object oriented method maybe

Comment: Well, actually you should be able to access those variables from _everywhere_ but only the callback of a click event is called, when the user clicks. So if you want your code called, when the user clicks, I see no other way than putting the code either inside the click-event or inside another function, that gets called inside the click-event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `window`-object could be just what you want.

Look at that:

```js
function setTest() {
  window.test = 'hello';
}
setTest();
document.write(test); // gives 'hello'
```

I don't know about other contexts but in the context of internet browsers, the `window`-object and all its members are available everywhere. Though it is more elegant to access them through the `window`-variable than directly.
What I want to say is:

**Don't do:**

```
test = 'hello';
alert(test);
```

**Instead do:**

```
window.test = 'hello';
alert(window.test);
```

**Even though, they have in fact the exact same meaning!** (if there is no hidden `var test;`)

But the first example will change its meaning completely, if `var test;` is called anywhere in the scope.

The second example on the other hand will stick with its meaning whether you add a `var test;` or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i tested it out I was able to do ' if(withones){
      alert("checked");
     }
     if(!withones){
      alert("unchecked");
     }`

Comment: Isn't that, what you wanted?

Comment: yea but I have a question im going to write but i accidentally hit enter I need like 5 min

Comment: @user2537537 np, dude ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i tested it out I was able to do ` if(withones){ alert("checked"); } if(!withones){ alert("unchecked"); }` this works in the click event. my question is lets say i have to do a procedure only when a box is checked.The main part of the app is if box is checked do this and there are alot of boxes that means I have to write all the code in the click event. I dont see a way to separate them for code cleanliness type of thing I hope you understand. thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @user2537537 What about a structure where the main code (which is different on each checked box if I understood you correct) is put into one `function` per functionality? Everything else is hard to discuss inside the comment section, you should write another question about that if you are really interested. You may copy big parts of your question here if you have not much time/patience - that does not hurt any StackOverflow-Rule :) (asking two questions inside one question in turn does hurt a StackOverflow-Rule)